# How hashmap inserts

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

Suppose that hashmap is created. By default it comes with 16 buckets. Is this a true statement?

> Size of hashmap will increase if the element size reaches threshold. The threshold is elementSize/BucketNUmber=12. In our example the bucket size is 16. so if I add 13th element it will increase bucket size from 16 to 32.

If this statement is true, what if the all element is stored in the same bucket? It is quite possible bcs we the location of new comer element is calculated by its hashcode. In this case we will have 15 more empty buckets. Does hashmap increase the bucket or not?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of resizing the hashmap is to get a better distribution of hashed items and to avoid collisions, and the performance penalties associated with collisions.  When Java increases the bucket size of the hashmap, it will also have to rehash every item contained in the map.  There is a cost with this as well, but it is one time and the hope is that the performance gain with a larger bucket size would outweigh this cost.

For reference, prior to Java 8, collisions in a hashmap would be resolved using a linked list, leading to `O(N)` worst search behavior for a map with `N` items.  As of Java 8, the `HashMap` class now uses a balanced tree to handle collisions, leading to a worst case search performance of `O(N*lgN)`.